# Custom code in all text between <>?

Tags: visual-editor, html-editor

I have a html tutorial based (like w3schools.com) Wordpress site which have around 200+ pages ans posts.

Our writer wrote all article in simple text format, but now we are making our post interesting to users. We decided to change, `<mytag>` to `<code><mytag></code>` (code tag changing its style to make it different from normal text).

Manually it is good for 10-15 pages and post but 200+ pages are huge amount. Can anyone suggest me a good way to do this in whole site?

Any suggestion will save me days.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Nothing helped me out, i manually changed it

Answer (score 0):

One option would be making these edits in bulk offline, working with a CSV file (in Excel perhaps).  The fantastic [WP CSV](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-csv/) plugin-in is a great tool for this.

Install the plugin, export your pages to edit, import the updated post data.  Done.